# React : api calls use old values of state variables

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ajax, react-hooks

I am trying to fetch data using an weather API on a form submission. For the first call, I get no result and then for the subsequent calls I get the result of the previous form input. What could be causing this ? This is how the on submit handler looks :

```
const [loc, setLoc] = useState("");
const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});



const handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
console.log(loc);
const url = `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${apikey}&q=${loc}&aqi=no`;
fetch(url)
  .then((res) => {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    setWeather(data);
    console.log(weather);
  });
  };
```

This is how the console looks like on making API calls :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setWeather` is the asynchronous method, and you can't get the updated value of `weather` immediately after `setWeather`.

```
    setWeather(data);
    console.log(weather); // This will display old state value of `weather`
```

You should use `useEffect` with adding a `weather` dependency to check updated state value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(weather);
}, [weather]);
```